# Avoid sqliteAssetHelper to log error

Tags: android, sqlite, logging

Hi guys i'have problem with this little block of code

```
// Insert a new contact in database
    public void insertInSignature(String TITLE_SI) {
        try {
            // Open Android Database
            db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put("TITLE_SI", TITLE_SI);
            db.insert("DELIVERY_SLIP", null, initialValues);
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            Log.e(TAG, "insertUser Error");
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception : " + sqle);
        } finally {
            // Close Android Database
            databaseHelper.close();
        }
    }
```

I have unique constraint on my table "DELIVERY_SLIP

So , when i'm trying to insert some row which already exist , it return some error like "Oh shit , you're inserting the same , i'm sorry men , i can't do it"

http://cdn.imghack.se/images/3b51afd07d1f1a8bd021c9e9dfc57e98.png

Here my log

It's this line

```
databaseHelper.close();
```

When database helper close , this return the log.
I just want to avoid to log it, I already tested with a tryCatch on sqliteConstraintException
But, nothing worked.
Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `insert()`, use [`insertWithOnConflict()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int)) with some conflict resolution algorithm appropriate for your use, such as `SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE`.